# Replace values between url using regEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I've been trying to find and replace width & height of an image using the following url

http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/c_fill,h_1024,w_768/v1453555296/manhattan_stater.jpg

as you notice h_1024,w_768  tells how the image should be scaled when i request from the cdn. according to my requirement this should be changeable via script ex resize(url,{500,500}) should be convert following url to

http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/c_fill,h_500,w_500/v1453555296/manhattan_stater.jpg

this is my code so far it's not perfect is there any way that could resolve this problem

```html
var url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/c_fill,h_1024,w_768/v1453555296/manhattan_stater.jpg";



var reg1 = /(\h_.*?\,)/gi;


 url = url.replace(reg1,"h_500,");

console.log(url);
```

Comment: `url.replace(/h_\d+/, "h_500")`

Comment: I would also do the replacement only in the token after /upload/, to avoid mismatches

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM9nD5/1).

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? This works as expected, wrap it in a function, use a similar pattern for width replacement, and you're on !

Comment: @Tushar thank you for the quick reply your regex work perfectly i'm currently  using

  url =  url.replace(/h_\d+/, "h_500").replace(/w_\d+/, "w_500");

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific regex here (that won't replace `h_1 in http://ite.com/h_2/upload/c_fill,h_1024,w_580`):

```
/(\/upload\/[^\/]*\bh_)\d+(,w_)\d+/
```

And replace with `"$1" + my_height + "$2" + my_width`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM9nD5/2)

```js
var mywidth = "800";
var myheight = "600";

var re = /(\/upload\/[^\/]*\bh_)\d+(,w_)\d+/; 
var str = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/c_fill,h_1024,w_768/v1453555296/manhattan_stater.jpg';
var subst = '$1' + myheight + '$2' + mywidth; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.write(result);
```

Regex matches:

- `(\/upload\/[^\/]*\bh_)` - Group 1 (back-referenced with `$1` in the replacement string) matching a literal character sequence `/upload/` (with `\/upload\/`), followed with zero or more characters other than `/` (with `[^\/]*`), and then followed by a word boundary `\b` with the literal sequence `h_`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(,w_)` - Group 2 (back-referenced with `$2` in the replacement string) matching a comma followed with a word character  followed with an underscore
- `\d+` - one or more digits

Comment: Please check this one is working for you any better. I think my answer is safer than what Tushar suggested.